# how to save new data and update data in a different table with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

How can i save a record new and update data in 2 different tables in laravel. I have perpustakaan table for to update. My second table is called peminjaman_buku for save new data. I hope you can help me, thank you very much

controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'kode_buku ' => 'required',
            'kode_peminjam' => 'required',
            'petugas_pinjam' => 'required',
            'tanggal_pinjam' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $status = "pinjam";
        $model = new P_Peminjaman;
        $model->kode_buku = $request->judul_buku;
        $model->kode_peminjam = $request->kode_peminjam;
        $model->petugas_pinjam = $request->petugas_pinjam;
        $model->tanggal_pinjam = $request->tanggal;
        $model->status = $status;
        
        $model->save();
        
        $modal = M_Perpustakaan::find($judul_buku);
        $modal->kode_buku = $request->judul_buku;
        $modal->status = $status;
        
        $modal->save();
        return redirect('ppeminjaman');

    }
```

when I do the process there is no updated data or new data in the database

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: `$judul_buku` is not defined, so `$modal` is `null` and no update will happen for that table.

Comment: thank you bro, i dont find value in $judul_buku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your modal code from this

```
$modal = M_Perpustakaan::find($judul_buku);
        $modal->kode_buku = $request->judul_buku;
        $modal->status = $status;
        
        $modal->save();
```

To this

```
$modal = M_Perpustakaan::find($judul_buku);
        $modal->update([
            'kode_buku' => $request->judul_buku,
            'status' => $status,
        ]);
```

Comment: i found this error : Undefined variable $judul_buku. if i by pass $modal, i get data $judul_buku in $model and save it to database

Comment: thank you, i found solution M_Perpustakaan::find($request->judul_buku);, working now. thank you very much

Comment: @indahwatiindahwati why did you accept this answer, it is not correct?

Comment: it is correct and i accept this answer, u can see i am select correct answer, for your answer idont find any button to say correct button

Comment: You said the solution is to use `$request->judul_buku` instead of `$judul_buku` ... This answer does not do that, the code here has the same error as your original code.  It is not correct ... ?

Comment: i using this : find($judul_buku); but i found null, when i using this find($request->judul_buku); i got value. i dont know what happens

Comment: But this answer does not suggest to use `find($request->judul_buku)`, so why accept it?